# Get ascii character set as ascii character set in servlet

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, xml-entities

Using jsp we print this `Hh&#8217;k` value in hidden field and then submit it. Then in servlet, we are getting it as parameter  `Hh'k`, instead we want this as `Hh&#8217;k`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please note that `&#8217;` represents a right single quotation mark `’`, not a simple apostrophe `'` as you've in your parameter value example.

Answer (score 2):

The browser don't do that because there's no reason. It just URL-encodes the special characters conform the `application/www-x-form-urlencoded` contract which is automatically URL-decoded by calling `getParameter()`.

If you really need to XML-escape them, you'd need to do it yourself after obtaining the request parameter. The [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) [`StringEscapeUtils#escapeXml()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml%28java.lang.String%29) is helpful in this:

```
String foo = request.getParameter("foo");
String escapedFoo = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(foo);
// ...
```

However, why would you do that? Do you have problems with redisplaying them in the HTML? For that there's a much easier solution, [just use UTF-8 everywhere](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html). E.g. add the following in top of your JSP:

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Etcetera.

Comment: There is no problem displaying it in the HTML, we have to maintain the same asscii charater while sending it another server.

Comment: I have tried StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml but its not working :(

Comment: Ah well, then go ahead escaping them yourself. Maybe you want to implement it in the API which is sending it to the other server instead of doing it for every inpue. Or perhaps you need to review the API which is doing the sending job if it's doing the job correctly. Does it take place by HTTP? Do you URL-encode the parameters using `URLEncoder` and so on?

Comment: How so not working? Please elaborate in more detail. I am unfortunately not immediately able to fly/beam over to you to see any error messages or unexpected results with my own eyes.

Comment: Actually the flow is, in jsp page we will get that "Hh&#8217;k" value and then will be submitted to a servlet and then write to a file. The value is seen in jsp page and after submission in servlet it is not seen as "Hh&#8217;k" instead as "Hh'k". We want that exact code so that we can write to a file.

Comment: Use `StringEscapeUtils`. The `System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml("Hh’k"));` gives here `Hh&#8217;k`, so I don't see any problems. In your question you have by the way a simple apostrophe (perhaps by typing mistake instead of literally copypasting?), which would be XML-escaped as `&apos;`. After all, it's still beyond me why you would it like that in the file. I still believe that you're looking for a solution for a certain and unclear problem in the wrong direction.

Comment: Oh, are you writing data to file as UTF-8 using `new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8")` and reading from it as UTF-8 by `new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8")`? Perhaps you aren't at all which would (incorreclty) force you to use XML entities. See also the "use UTF-8 everywhere" link in my answer.